# ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++ error while compiling c++ program

Tags: c++, mingw

Compiling a simple C++ Hello World program from windows terminal by: `g++ main.cpp` gives this error:

```
d:/softwares/mingw/bin/...../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
d:/softwares/mingw/bin/...../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
d:/softwares/mingw/bin/...../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello C++!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

MinGW path is set up on windows

Comment: Looks like a broken compiler installation, or several conflicting installations. I'd remove all of them and install the one from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075

Comment: I agree remove the broken most likely older version of mingw and install the current one using msys2.

Comment: Thanks for help, I reinstalled from above link and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `g++` as linker instead of `ld`.